# can someone help me with preg_match?

Tags: preg-match

i can't find solution how to read correctly the message, this is model of message:

```
209937
Maks ) Message

11:52
Tedy...Hi 12:01
Maks )Hello12:07
Tedy...How are you?

Update Messages
Delete all messages
MyPage Messages
```

I need to check if message is sent, the model of message is it: first line is sent time, next line is

nickname and message, also time of next message

```
[hh:mm1]
[Nickname1][Message1][hh:mm2]
[Nickname2][Message2][hh:mm3]
[Nickname1][Message3]
```

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Comment: Looking at the messages, format seems not easily understandable.

Comment: i think i can check message by reading after [Nickname] but my knowledge of preg_match is too poor((

Comment: If the language is regular regular expression should be able to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$sample_text = <<<EOF
209937
Maks ) Message

11:52
Tedy...Hi
12:01
Maks )Hello )
12:07
Tedy...How are you?

Update Messages
Delete all messages
MyPage Messages
EOF;

preg_match_all('/(?\'time\'(\d{1,2}\:\d{2}))[^\w]*(?\'who\'(\w+))(?\'what\'([^\d]+))/', $sample_text, $messages);

echo '<pre>' . print_r($messages, true) . '</pre>';
?>
```